# Matrix norms and the matrix transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, transpose, matrix-norms

There are three parts to this question, and I'm not sure how they link together to provide answers.

$A$ is a linear mapping from Euclidean space $X$ to Euclidean space $U$, and the norm $\| \cdot \|$ is the Euclidean norm for matrices.

(i) Show that $\|A^{T}\| = \|A\|$.

(ii) Let $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a unit vector, and $\sigma u = Av$, with $\sigma = \|Av\|$. Therefore, $u\in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is also a unit vector. Does it follow that $\sigma v = A^{T}u$?

(iii) Now if $v$ is as above, but $\sigma = \|A\|$. Show that $\sigma v = A^{T}u$.

Comment: First thing to do is to provide the definition of $\|\cdot\|$. There are many matrix norms and you did not specify which one you refer to.

Comment: For (ii), it is not clear what you're asking for

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro from (iii) it appears that this is the induced $2$-norm, i.e. the "spectral norm".

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro A is a mapping from and into Euclidean spaces, and the norm is the Euclidean norm. I will edit the question.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I suppose that the question for (ii) is simply - is it true that $\sigma v = A^{T}u$, based on the specification of the vectors?

Comment: what have you tried ?

Comment: @FMcA Okay, that makes sense now.  What does $\sigma = Av$ mean?

Comment: @AhmadBazzi I couldn't figure out how to move forward for any of it.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Sorry, I corrected the question, because I failed to put the norm in.

Comment: The fact that $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a unit vector and $\sigma u = Av$ with $\sigma = \|Av\|$ is not enough to deduce that $\sigma v = A^Tu$, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Ok. Why is that the case? And does the redefinition in (iii) allow us to conclude that $\sigma v = A^{T}u$? Because then $\|A\| = \|Av\|$.

Comment: @FMcA before I start writing an answer, it would help if you could provide some context.  For instance: what are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried? Could you elaborate on your statement "I'm not following it"?  That is, what exactly do you find confusing here?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom For (i), I have an intuitive idea of why the norms are equivalent, because the elements are the same in both matrices (they are simply in different positions). But I am not sure how to prove it. For (ii) and (iii), I do not know where to begin answering the questions. Individually, the definitions make sense to me, but I cannot put them together.

Comment: @FMcA Perfecct, thank you. Last question: have you already covered [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) or polar decomposition in your class or textbook?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom No, we've not covered either of these topics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your intuitive idea for (i) is nice, but difficult to implement since $\|A\|$ cannot be nicely written as a function of the entries of $A$. One approach to (i) is as follows.  Note that
$$
\|A\|^2 = \max_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\|^2 = \max_{\|x\| = 1} (Ax)^T(Ax) = \max_{\|x\| = 1}x^T(A^TA)x.
$$
By the Rayleigh-Ritz theorem, this is simply the largest eigenvalue of $A^TA$, and the vector at which we attain this maximum is the corresponding eigenvector.  Similarly, $\|A^T\|^2$ must be the largest eigenvalue of $AA^T$.  Since $A^TA$ and $AA^T$ have the same non-zero eigenvalues (this can be proven in several ways), we conclude that $\|A\| = \|A^T\|$.

(ii): This will not hold in general.  For instance, consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}, \quad  u = v = \pmatrix{1\\0}, \quad \sigma = 1.
$$
We indeed have $\sigma u = Av$, but we do not have $A^Tu = \sigma v$.

(iii):  The key is to observe that in the case that by the Rayleigh Ritz theorem (as discussed in the first part of this answer), $\|Av\| = \|A\|$ implies that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A^TA$ with $A^TAv = \|A\|^2v$.  Thus, with $\sigma = \|A\|$ and the definitions from (ii), we have the following.

If $\sigma = \|A\| = 0$, then it follows that $A = 0$ and the result follows trivially.  In the case where $\sigma \neq 0$, we have
$$
A^Tu = A^T \left(\frac {Av}{\sigma}\right) = \frac 1{\sigma} A^TA v = \frac 1{\sigma} \sigma^2 v = \sigma v
$$
as was desired.